# How to Clear Cell(s) based on the Value of another Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I am looking for a script that will clear cell(s) when the value of another cell changes or is equal to ("X").
 [image: capture1]

In the attachment I would like when Column "G" gets checked marked (TRUE), then Columns "D" & "E" become cleared (or no value) according to the respective row that was checked (TRUE).

For Example:

When "G3" is checked (TRUE), then D3 & E3 are cleared. As you can see that it is important that both columns get cleared out as it affects Columns "E", "F", and "H" which all include very important information that needs to be automatically updated according to Column "G" to remove as much human error as possible.
[image: Capture2]

I have done some research on my own searching through this site, other sites and forums, and google support, etc. There was one that was close to this that I wanted, but it would "hide" the row, which I don't want and supposedly it would clear a cell but I couldn't get that to work. i attempted to make my own edits but I do not have experience enough to troubleshoot.

Here is something that I found and couldn't troubleshoot:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (sh.getName() !== 'Sheet2' || e.range.columnStart !== 3 || e.range.rowStart < 2 || e.value !== 'No') return;
    e.range.offset(0, 3).clearContent()
    sh.hideRows(e.range.rowStart)
}
```

Then change the highlighted text to the name of the sheet/tab you want the script to work on.
Finally close the script editor (!) and navigate to that sheet. Try entering 'No' in col C and see what happens.

I edited it to be:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (sh.getName() !== 'Main' || e.range.columnStart !== 7 || e.range.rowStart < 2 || e.value !== 'FALSE') return;
    e.range.offset(0, 3).clearContent()
    sh.hideRows(e.range.rowStart)
}
```

I can get it to hide the row (which I don't want), but I can't get it to clear a cell, let alone two of them.

Here is what I have from Raymond Tran's answer (good workaround for now):

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to Clear a Cell based on the Value of another Cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/137438/88163). If you want to improve your question it's better to edit the original post instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Thank you, I do not have access to edit that previous question and so that is why I duplicated to be able to edit as necessary and have more "control" over when there are comments or answers.

Comment: It looks that you have more than one account. Please follow the instructions of [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: In the mean time, please read  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets 
 and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thank you for the help Rubén, put in a request with the site. Yes, I have done some research on my own searching through this site, other sites and forums, and google support, etc.
There was one that was close to this that I wanted, but it would "hide" the row, which I don't want and supposedly it would clear a cell but I couldn't get that to work. i attempted to make my own edits but I do not have experience enough to troubleshoot.

Comment: There you go, I think that is about as good as I can get it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know what you think about this solution. Column D and E can be grouped. Add two extra columns with the formula in my screenshot. Work of the two new columns and update other formulas to reference your new columns.

Formula: `=IF(C2=true,value("$0"),A2)`

[image]

Comment: This is a great workaround, and I understand the sheet. Hopefully, there is a way to do this without adding extra columns to avoid confusion when someone looks at this.
So I titled columns as the false total and false aging and then the ones with your equation as True total and true aging.
Thank you for this.
The Ctrl+G doesn't seem to be working for me so I can't show you the images of your answer but I will add it to the question of before and afters.

Answer (score 1):

The code line that hides the row is

```
sh.hideRows(e.range.rowStart)
```

To avoid that the row be hidden, just remove that line.

The code line that clears a a cell content is

```
e.range.offset(0, 3).clearContent()
```

It's clearing a cell in the same row, three columns to the right, i.e. if G3 is edited then the content of `J3` is cleared. To clear the content of C3 and D3 change the above code line by

```
e.range.offset(0, -4, 1, 2).clearContent()
```

Reference

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: Thank you Rubén, I still don't seem to be able to get it to "clear" the cell of value.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Awesome, it worked,,,, can you explain how the C3 and D3 were cleared?
I would want D3 and E3 cleared.

Comment: @DreamLvg I added a reference.

Comment: Awesome. Now should I ask this in another question?:

Now I Froze the top two rows (the titles and the "main" totals [put the totals above the titles so that when I apply the filter to the titles they will still always be showing]). The Question is:
Is there a way to (dependent on the filter applied), that those "main" totals auto adjust to the filter? Or "too" complicated?
So if someone sorts by vendor, the column of total past due and the total a/p adjust to that sorted list. and when it is unsorted it goes back to calculating the whole list.

Comment: @DreamLvg Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Regarding if you should ask in a another question, yes, please ask that by posting a new question.

Answer (score -2):

Currently this works great when I change col 12 (L) to "Cancel"  If I also wanted to clear cells if col 12 (L) was changed to "Changed"  How would I modify the script?  I other words, I'd like to perform the function if col 12 was either "Cancel" OR "Changed".

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/155546)